# How to save a string globally?

Tags: android

I want to ask if is it possible to store a string globally for me to call in any other activity? Like for example the String email in my code, I want to save it globally so I can call it from other activity.

I tried using intent to carry data but it does not seem to work for my code.

```
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (!error) {
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Create login session
                            session.setLogin(true);

                            // Launch main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                    MainActivity.class);




                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // Error in login. Get the error message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "login");
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to save data to preference and use it any `Activity`.

You can use this method to save your `email` `String` into `SharedPreferences`.

```
public void saveValueToPrefrence(Context mContext, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserData", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

You can get `email` `String` in any other `Activity` using below method:

```
public String getValueFromPrefrence(Context mContext, String key) {
    SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserData", 0);
    return pref.getString(key, "");
}
```

You can use this method to save your `email` `String`:

```
saveValueToPrefrence(ActivityName.this,"email",email)
```

You can get `email` `String` like this:

```
String email = getValueFromPrefrence(ActivityName.this,"email")
```

Basically you need `Activity's Context` to save and get value from `SharedPreferences`.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use global variable, but most of the time you shouldn't use this.

[Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

You have to know if this variable is used in most of your application (lot of class need an access to it, and be careful about threads to not have a concurrency issue). If it's the case you can maybe use a global, which is a bad idea in my opinion. You also can do a singleton class.

But if you just try to send your variable between two view, I think you should use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

@FreeYourSoul is correct.

But as an answer to this question, there are multiple ways to do this. The easiest way would be to simply create a Static class that has a hashmap inside it that you can manipulate with any class.

Likely not your best choice, but it certainly is possible